# Is there any way to close Eventhubconsumerclient.receive if it has been a while without any messages?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I just implemented eventhub with version 5, which has been changed a bit from previous version.

current running code is following:

```
consumer_client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR,
                                                  consumer_group='fconsumer',
                                                  eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME)
consumer_client.receive(on_event=on_event, 
                        partition_id = "0", 
                        track_last_enqueued_event_properties=False, 
                        starting_position="@latest")
```

By adding an argument for the time duration (or keep_alive ag from prev version), I would make it stop receiving messages and close it after a certain amount of time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

consumer_client.receive(...) will be a blocking call and it won't return on its own. You need to create a thread for consuming events and in the main thread you can get to decide when to close the consumer client. Sample code snippet as below...

```
thread = threading.Thread(
    target=consumer_client.receive,
    kwargs={
        "on_event": on_event,
        "on_partition_initialize": on_partition_initialize,
        "on_partition_close": on_partition_close,
        "on_error": on_error,
        "starting_position": "-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    }
)

thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
time.sleep(RECEIVE_DURATION)
consumer_client.close()
thread.join()
```

Comment: My point is I would like to add an argument for the consumer_client not adding additional thread, and I have no idea how time.sleep control and make this thread stop when there's no further activity on the client.

Comment: Threading is the only option for now. Please take a look at to this sample - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/recv_for_period_async.py

Comment: Just to add a bit of context: the team working on the Python client library is aware this is a pain point and would like to add the ability for the receive call to return after a period of time if no events are available.  At present, there are discussions taking place around potential designs for doing so.

I can't make any guarantees at this point in time, but I'm hopeful that this is an enhancement that you'll see in a release in the near future.